# IOS build fails for MFP Cordova-Ionic project

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, mobilefirst-cli

I am trying to build my `MFP cordova Ionic` based hybrid application created using `CLI`. It works perfect for android but it fails when I try to build it for iOS. There are multiple errors which I am facing

> xcodebuild[14887:399060] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 7FDF5C7A-131F-4ABB-9EDC-8C5F8F0B8A90 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/VVDocumenter-Xcode.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs

I tried resolving this issue by adding required missing `key-val in plist file`

When I try to run it from Xcode I am getting error - `Some keys are missing in worklight.plist`

After adding missing keys now I am getting

> 2016-05-04 17:50:28.507 StoreApp[14787:396490] [FATAL] [WL_INIT] -[WLImpl initWL] in WLImpl.m:180 :: Init failure: Can't read checksum.js, The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 258.), (null). Reinstall the application and try again.

Even I have tried running simple MFP cordova project,but build fails for this

Answer (score 0):

> Even I have tried running simple MFP cordova project,but build fails for this

I cannot reproduce this...

> idanadar@mbp-idan:~/Desktop$ mfp cordova create
>   ? Enter name of app: myapp
>   ? Enter the package ID: com.ibm.myapp
>   ? Enter the app version: 1.0.0
>   ? Select platforms to be supported by your app: ios
>   ? The following plugins will be automatically added to your app:
>   cordova-plugin-mfp
>   org.apache.cordova.device
>   org.apache.cordova.dialogs
>   org.apache.cordova.geolocation
>   org.apache.cordova.globalization
>   org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
>   org.apache.cordova.network-information
>
> Please press enter to continue...
>   ? Select additional plugins you would like to add:
>   ? Enter a path to an app template to be added: cordova-hello-world-mfp
>   Embedded Cordova Command: cordova create "myapp" "com.ibm.myapp" "myapp" --copy-from="/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/cordovacmd/cordova/templates/cordova-hello-world-mfp"
>   Adding ios project...
>   Adding "cordova-plugin-mfp"
>   Installing "cordova-plugin-mfp" for ios
>   Installing "org.apache.cordova.device" for ios
>   Installing "org.apache.cordova.dialogs" for ios
>   Installing "org.apache.cordova.geolocation" for ios
>   Installing "org.apache.cordova.globalization" for ios
>   Installing "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" for ios
>   Installing "org.apache.cordova.network-information" for ios
>   Plugin install completed
>   If you made changes to your main.m file, please manually merge main.m.bak with MFP's main.m
>   Plugin "cordova-plugin-mfp" added successfully.
>   Preparing for push...
>   MFP App settings not found, configuring..
>   Embedded Cordova Command: cordova prepare ios 
>   /Users/idanadar/Desktop/myapp/mobilefirst/com_ibm_myapp-iphone-1.0.0.wlapp has been built.
>   Push Completed Successfully.
>   MFP Cordova project created successfully.
>   idanadar@mbp-idan:~/Desktop$ cd myapp/
>   idanadar@mbp-idan:~/Desktop/myapp$ mfp cordova run --platform ios

The iOS Simulator then started and the application was displayed.

As for creating an Ionic-based app using MFP Cordova, I suggest that you will follow this: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/03/23/working-with-ibm-mobilefirst-and-the-ionic-framework/

Comment: Is MFP Push necessary before running the project on device? For android apk was getting generated without MFP push and same thing fails for iOS. After pushing the iOS application on the server I am able to run it on device now Thanks Idan Adar